# Unusual "Google Cloud Print" notification

Tags: 16.04, google

I received the following notification this morning, which does not look like the typical system notification.

**(1)** Is it possible, in general, to find which application or service launched this notification? And, in this specific case, I don't understand why I would have gotten this notification. I don't use many cloud or Google services, and I don't recall installing or signing-up for Google Cloud Print. I have Chromium installed, but I am not signed in. **(2)** Is this notification a sign that something has been installed on my machine without my knowledge?

[image: Notification: Google Cloud Print - New printer on your network...]

The text reads:

```
Google Cloud Print
New printer on your network
Add the printer to Google Cloud Print so you can print from anywhere.
(Add to cloud print) (Don't show this)
```

Comment: Sorry for the sparse tags, I would think something like "notifications" would be appropriate, but one wasn't available. Please add a relevant and helpful tag if there is one.

Comment: I also just started receiving this.  I do not have Chrome installed on my computer.  I have Chromium, Vivaldi and Opera as browsers.  How did Google cloud get installed on my computer? Ubuntu 16.04 w Cinnamon desktop

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I received this in ubuntu 20.04, and I do not have chromium installed. It is not a system notification, and it is not a firefox notification. This is quite concerning.

Comment: @nsheff I have just recently found a related setting in Chromium (`chrome://settings/cloudPrinters`) that probably accounts for it. But I don't know of anything that should have triggered if you don't have Chromium installed. However, it's possible that running *any* Google app/service on your machine will have the "Google Cloud Print" setting embedded in it somewhere.

Comment: @nivk The only thing I can think of is that it's coming from an electron app, which is based on chromium. It's got to be a bug and a security concern that such an app would be listening for and notifying of available printers.